# Debug remotely on STM32CubeIDE with an STM32 eval board

Tags: gdb, stm32, gdbserver, openocd

I want to setup the following environment: I've got a STM32H753I-EVAL2 eval board, connected on a Windows PC. Until now I was developping and debugging locally on this PC with STM32CubeIDE. For several reasons my code source is on a Linux server (Samba mounting) so it takes forever to build a project. Hence I want to develop on the linux server from my Windows machine.

Compiling is working fine (and is way faster) but the issue is about debugging. I know it is possible to debug remotely, the Debug Configuration window from Eclipse (I'm using OpenOcd) allows to connect to a remote GDB server. What I don't know is how to start a GDB server on the Windows machine that will connect to the STM32 board ?

Comment: (I don't have an answer, but...) Sounds like a weird setup. Why not just do everything locally, but have a remote git repository on your Linux server that you push to every day? This way your files are all building, working, and running on your *local* machine, while still having a copy of them all on your *remote* machine.

Comment: I agree it would be better. But unfortunately I cannot do what I want on this machine.

Comment: @GabrielStaples regardless of whether OP's setup is weird, it is still a valid question. Eclipse supports debugging using the gdb client-server model, and the fact that model uses TCP should allow for `gdbserver` and `gdb` to be run on different machines. As it stands, Eclipse seems to allow you create a configuration which launches `gdb` on its own, but there is not an obvious way launching the complementary `gdbserver` on its own.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the "answer to myself" but I think it might be useful for others (and even to me when I have forgotten in a few weeks ;) ).

Here is how to do.

- on host side (on the machine where the eval board is physically plugged in) you have to manually launch the GDB server application that comes with STM32CubeIDE installation. See STMicro application note UM2576 for details. The default command line is:

`ST-LINK_gdbserver.exe -d -v -cp "C:\ST\STM32CubeIDE_1.0.0.19w12patch\STM32CubeIDE\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.cubeprogrammer.win32_1.0.0.201903011553\tools\bin"`

- Now you've done the hardest. On server/remote side you have to setup the Debug Configuration to use OpenOcd with option "Connect to remote GDB server" and simply enter IP address and port number (which is not 3333 by default but 61234, but it can be modified).

This setup is working fine, even if I encoutered some instabilities during debugging once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

I see two (maybe three) options

- Use an alternate GDB server (see below)
- Run the GDB server from STMCubeIDE in isolation (see OP's answer for Windows, this answer for Linux)
- GDB Serial (not really an option right now but I'll share my experience so far)

***I have used the second option to succesfully debug my target using arbitary GDBs such as `gdb-multiarch` command line and in the (non STMCube-ified) Eclipse CDT***

**Alternative GDB Servers**

You could try [STLink open source](https://github.com/stlink-org/stlink). I did. The problem is, your device might not be supported properly. I built 1.6.1 from Github to enable support for STM32G03x device. While moving to this version enabled it to detect the device, and I can use `st-flash` to program the device, the debugger is unusable (try and alter a register, it alters the wrong one, try and single step a program, it crashes immediately).

Do try it though .. it's easy and quick to install (or build), so it's worth checking if your device will work correctly with it.

Openocd is another option, but seems not to support SWD connection. I tried a build that allegedly had a patch for this but no luck.

If you can get one of these open source alternatives to work, they have another advantage, you may be able run them on something like a Raspberry PI, which means you don't have to get a PC physically close to your target.

**Run the GDB server from STMCubeIDE in isolation**

For Windows, see the OP's answer. For Linux, I do this ***alter the pathnames to suit your installation***

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/user/apps/st/stm32cubeide_1.5.1/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.stlink-gdb-server.linux64_1.5.0.202011040924/tools/bin/native/linux_x64/ /home/user/apps/st/stm32cubeide_1.5.1/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.stlink-gdb-server.linux64_1.5.0.202011040924/tools/bin/ST-LINK_gdbserver -p 61234 -l 1 -d -s -cp /home/user/apps/st/stm32cubeide_1.5.1/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.cubeprogrammer.linux64_1.5.0.202011040924/tools/bin -m 0 -k
```

How did I get to this? Firstly launched a debugging session from STMCubeIDE, then ran

```
ps aux | grep gdbserver
```

Then we can see how Eclipse (STMCube) is launching the `gdbserver` and work from there.

If you find it complains about a `.so` file, locate that file from the STMCube installation and ensure the path to the directory containing it is in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (as per my example)

You can also launch the program with --help to show more options.

If add -e (persistent) you can disconnect and reconnect a GDB client without resetting the target (it will reset on initial invocation of the gdb server though, even without -k).

**GDB Serial**

This is where the target implements the GDB server end of the protocol. The GDB stub usually runs in an exception handler. This would usually be your breakpoint handler but you can also make it the default handler for unhandled exceptions, or, for example, the ctrl-c interrupt.

I have done a lot of Googling about this recently and basically when people ask about it on forums they usually get responses along the lines of "Here be dragons" or "Why don't you use JTAG?"

So the drivers for this, you might like to know, are in the GDB sources  `git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git` under `gdb/stubs`. The documentation is [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Remote-Stub.html). ***There isn't a stub implementation there for arm.*** Which is sad really, I used to use GDB remote serial regularly  where I worked, and some of those targets were indeed ARM. The operating system was ecos.

So could ecos GDB stubs be ported to bare metal? Having giving it a good coat of looking at, I believe yes they could. The stubs are based on the ones from the GDB sources but they are heavily polluted with Ecos and Redboot build macros and copyright (the ogiringals were written by HP and released without copyright). We don't know what bugs the Ecos stubs may contain (I fixed at least one back in the day and I don't recall whether I submitted a patch). We don't know if they really support the latests architectures properly. And, we don't know if, after that, they simply use up too much memory - my STM32 has 8K of SRAM and I already see buffers that have a default size of 2K (not saying that's necessary but you see how work needs to be done here..)

So this third option, I will revisit this one day but for now, for me, it's a nope.